# how to retrieve a non sa password in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, password-recovery

Is it possible to retrieve (if the user has sa rights) the password of a user in SQL Server 2008 R2?

The scenario is this: I need to automatically store in a document the list of all usernames and passwords, but without changing the password, just reading the actual password.

Is this possible or not?

Comment: [Not according to here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic664614-391-2.aspx)

Comment: Yes it seems not possible according to that, but may be there is a way... let's wait for some other feedback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can for SQL logins.

You read the hashed passwords [sys.sql_logins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174355.aspx) (maybe only via the [DAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189595%28SQL.90%29.aspx)) and use a tool like [NGS SQLCrack](http://www.ngssecure.com/ngssecure/services/information-security-software/ngs-sqlcrack.aspx).

However, there is almost *no* requirement ever to keep these in a document.

For Windows based logins, no. The password is in AD.

And read this: ["What are the arguments for and against a network policy where the sys admin knows users passwords?"](https://serverfault.com/questions/21218/what-are-the-arguments-for-and-against-a-network-policy-where-the-sys-admin-knows/21221#21221)

Comment: Just to add some credibility to this, right now, your passwords are protected by them being hashed and only viewable to those with sa (or, more specifically, the control server permission).  Are you going to do a better job than that at protecting this document?  Also, anyone with sa can impersonate anyone else on the server.  Does that satisfy your requirement?  How about the ability to change any SQL login password?

Comment: @Ben Thul: not quite sure what your point is sorry. The fact is that sa can brute force your sql passwords... and I have done for DR purposes. One reason to insist on windows author, no?

Comment: I was supporting your answer, not disagreeing with it.  As to my point, all I'm saying is that it's unlikely that the author will be able to do a better job than SQL server at protecting the passwords.